# Opening a Page in FreshMVVM from a Push Notification and onward Navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2401
- FreshMVVM 4.0.1
- Android and iOS

I am trying to open a page using FreshMVVM. If the app is already running I want to plug into the exisiting navigation stack.

The page opens fine but when we try and navigate the user onward by pushing a new page onto the stack i get the following Exception

> FreshTinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException: 'Resolve failed: IFreshNavigationService'

With a Call Stack of:

```
 at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal (FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer+TypeRegistration registration, FreshTinyIoC.NamedParameterOverloads parameters, FreshTinyIoC.ResolveOptions options) [0x00136] in <244cbb4b2b78473caee762c4138df3f3>:0 
 at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type resolveType, System.String name) [0x00013] in <244cbb4b2b78473caee762c4138df3f3>:0 
 at FreshTinyIoC.FreshTinyIoCContainer.Resolve[ResolveType] (System.String name) [0x00001] in <244cbb4b2b78473caee762c4138df3f3>:0 
 at FreshMvvm.FreshTinyIOCBuiltIn.Resolve[ResolveType] (System.String name) [0x00006] in <c1f1d60a460941bc82899cfb78f0c2ec>:0 
 at FreshMvvm.PageModelCoreMethods.PushPageModelWithPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, FreshMvvm.FreshBasePageModel pageModel, System.Object data, System.Boolean modal, System.Boolean animate) [0x001ca] in <c1f1d60a460941bc82899cfb78f0c2ec>:0
```

This comes from the following call to `PushPageModel`

```
return new FreshAwaitCommand(async (entryType, tcs) =>
{
    await this.CoreMethods.PushPageModel(typeof(SignalHistoryViewModel), null, false, true);
    tcs.SetResult(true);
});
```

The code I use to load the page when responding to the Notifcation tap is below. Note if there is **not** an existing Navigation I create a new container, if there is an existing one I want to Push onto that one. I am assuming that FreshMVVM is correctly initialised because otherwise I would not be able to load the first page after the tapping on Notification. The exception only throws when I try and load then next Page

```
Type viewModelType = Helpers.SignalStateToViewModelHelper.GetSignalDetailViewModelType((State)Enum.Parse(typeof(State), signalState));

var navigationStack = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;

if (navigationStack != null)
{
    // Navigate within the existing navigation stack
    var pageModel = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel(viewModelType, true);

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        await navigationStack.PushAsync(FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel(viewModelType, null));
    });
}
else
{
    // Create a new navigation stack
    var pageModel = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel(viewModelType, true);
    var navigationContainer = new FreshNavigationContainer(pageModel);

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = navigationContainer;
    });
}
```

If I always create a new container the code never fails but that means it is a new Navigation and I cannot press back in the stack.

Comment: It probably has to do with TinyIoC not being ready when you try and resolve your page, Your application is barely alive at this point your DI won't be able to resolve its Pages/ViewModels at this moment

Comment: This Exception is not thrown until I try and move on to ANOTHER page. At the point the  exception is thrown the page loaded from the Notifcation tap is displaying fine and bound to its ViewModel. Therefore the application is very much "alive"

Comment: I see in that case maybe it has to do with the naming convention maybe make sure your naming convention for your page and view model match FreshMvvM requirements. Also, why are you not using Coremethods to Push something to the Navigation stack? Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: "Also, why are you not using Coremethods to Push something to the Navigation stack" I am running in code fired when the app handles the tap on a Notifcation so I do not have access to IPageModelCoreMethods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by explicitly registering a IFreshNavigationService.

`FreshIOC.Container.Register<IFreshNavigationService>(freshNavigationContainer, Constants.DefaultNavigationServiceName);`

This might sound like a "Doh!" or RTFM moment but it still surprises me because I am pushing the page into a running instance that obviously does have an IFreshNavigationService registered otherwise it would not have worked up to that point.

I can only assume that this is because I do properly understand the App lifecycle and when the page is created in code running from a Notification "delegate" it is running in a different context.